# How to restrict accessing of an Arraylist and disallow change?

Tags: java, arraylist, immutability

How could I restrict the accessing (retrieving/inserting/updating/deleting) of an Arraylist and disallow changes to its values?

I had faced this question in an interview.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by restrict retrieving?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A classic solution is to wrap it using [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList%28java.util.List%29).

For example:

```
List<Integer> sourceList;
// ...
List<Integer> readOnlyList = Collections.unmodifiableList(sourceList);
```

This will prevent everything except reading. If you want to prevent reading, make it `private`.